# GtkTable overlapping widgets

Tags: c, gtk

I have a GtkTable with a background (an image widget spanning the whole dimensions of the table) and at one point I want to add another image widget on top of the background. It seems that, while I attach the second image after the background, it still shows below it. How can I deal with image priority and select which images will be shown over the others?

Comment: Note that the [GtkTable](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTable.html) widget is deprecated. Please don't use it in newly written code.

Comment: @unwind I'm working with Gtk2+